# Copying annotations with PdfWriter instead of PdfCopy

Tags: itext, pdf-writer

I need to copy annotations using PdfWriter instead of PdfCopy because at the time of the copy I need to resize/rotate the page. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You can resize/rotate pages using `PdfCopy`, too.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do it using pdfCopy, because in the chapter 6, page 188 in the subtitle "Preservation of Interative Features" in the book IText n Action (second edition), described that is not possible to. The text excerpt is: "You’ve used imported pages with PdfWriter in section 6.2 and with PdfStamper in section 6.3. You’ve scaled these imported pages, rotated them, and so on. All of this isn’t
possible with the PdfImportedPage objects obtained from PdfCopy . You can only add them to a new document in their original form and size."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You think you need to use a plain `PdfWriter` instead of a `PdfCopy` for copying PDFs because you* need to resize/rotate the page *and iText in Action, 2nd Ed, says doing so is not possible with the `PdfCopy` class. Thus, you look for a way to copy annotations in such a context.*

*What you should look for instead is a way to rotate or resize pages and at the same time use `PdfCopy` nonetheless!*

While it is true that the `PdfCopy` class **itself** does not allow resizing or rotating pages, you can manipulate a PDF loaded into a `PdfReader` and resize and/or rotate its pages **before** using the `PdfCopy` class. If you then copy the pages from this manipulated `PdfReader` into a `PdfCopy`, you get a result with resized or rotated pages (due to the manipulated `PdfReader`) and all the annotations present (due to the use of a `PdfCopy`).

E.g. you can resize all the pages in a `PdfReader` like this:

```java
void resize(PdfReader pdfReader, float width, float height) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        boolean switched = pdfReader.getPageRotation(i) % 180 != 0;
        float widthHere = switched ? height : width;
        float heightHere = switched ? width : height;

        Rectangle cropBox = pdfReader.getCropBox(i);
        float halfWidthGain = (widthHere - cropBox.getWidth()) / 2;
        float halfHeightGain = (heightHere - cropBox.getHeight()) / 2;
        Rectangle newCropBox = new Rectangle(cropBox.getLeft() - halfWidthGain, cropBox.getBottom() - halfHeightGain,
                cropBox.getRight() + halfWidthGain, cropBox.getTop() + halfHeightGain);

        Rectangle mediaBox = pdfReader.getPageSize(i);
        Rectangle newMediaBox = new Rectangle(Math.min(newCropBox.getLeft(), mediaBox.getLeft()),
                Math.min(newCropBox.getBottom(), mediaBox.getBottom()),
                Math.max(newCropBox.getRight(), mediaBox.getRight()),
                Math.max(newCropBox.getTop(), mediaBox.getTop()));

        PdfDictionary pageDictionary = pdfReader.getPageN(i);
        pageDictionary.put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, new PdfArray(new float[] {newMediaBox.getLeft(), newMediaBox.getBottom(),
                newMediaBox.getRight(), newMediaBox.getTop()}));
        pageDictionary.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, new PdfArray(new float[] {newCropBox.getLeft(), newCropBox.getBottom(),
                newCropBox.getRight(), newCropBox.getTop()}));
    }
}
```

*([CopyWithResizeRotate](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/copy/CopyWithResizeRotate.java#L109) helper method)*

and you can rotate all the pages in a `PdfReader` like this:

```java
void rotate(PdfReader pdfReader) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        int rotation = pdfReader.getPageRotation(i);
        int newRotation = rotation + 90 % 360;

        PdfDictionary pageDictionary = pdfReader.getPageN(i);
        if (newRotation == 0)
            pageDictionary.remove(PdfName.ROTATE);
        else
            pageDictionary.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(newRotation));
    }
}
```

*([CopyWithResizeRotate](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/copy/CopyWithResizeRotate.java#L140) helper method)*

Using these helpers, you can e.g. create a PDF from the rotated and/or resized pages of some source PDF and copy them like this:

```java
byte[] wildPdf = RETRIEVE_SOURCE_PDF;

PdfReader pdfReaderOriginal = new PdfReader(wildPdf);
PdfReader pdfReaderRotate = new PdfReader(wildPdf);
rotate(pdfReaderRotate);
PdfReader pdfReaderResize = new PdfReader(wildPdf);
resize(pdfReaderResize, PageSize.LETTER.getWidth(), PageSize.LETTER.getHeight());
PdfReader pdfReaderRotateResize = new PdfReader(wildPdf);
rotate(pdfReaderRotateResize);
resize(pdfReaderRotateResize, PageSize.LETTER.getWidth(), PageSize.LETTER.getHeight());

try (   OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "wild-rotated-resized.pdf"))) {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy pdfCopy = new PdfCopy(document, os);
    document.open();
    pdfCopy.addDocument(pdfReaderOriginal);
    pdfCopy.addDocument(pdfReaderRotate);
    pdfCopy.addDocument(pdfReaderResize);
    pdfCopy.addDocument(pdfReaderRotateResize);
    document.close();
}
```

*([CopyWithResizeRotate](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/copy/CopyWithResizeRotate.java#L78) test method `testRotateResizeAndCopy`)*

The result can look as follows, the first row the original pages (#1 A4, #2 HALFLETTER, #3 A5, #4 A5 rotated, #5 500x700), the second row the rotated ones, the third row the resized ones (to LETTER), and the fourth row the rotated and resized ones (to LETTER). The Adobe Reader thumbnails unfortunately are not at all to scale:

[image: screen shot]

#### Manipulating a single PDF only

If you actually only want to resize/rotate pages of a single input PDF, you should not use a `PdfCopy` instance but instead a `PdfStamper`:

```java
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
[...manipulate properties of the pdfReader like above...]
new PdfStamper(pdfReader, TARGET_STREAM).close();
```

The advantage here is that not only page-level data but also document-level data of the original document are retained.

#### Special annotations

There is one type of annotations which will behave in an unexpected manner with the code above: annotations with the **NoRotate** flag set. Such annotations will behave like this when their host page is rotated:

[image: screenshot from specification]

*(ISO 32000-2 section 12.5.3 — Annotation flags)*

Comment: Thank you! I did not imagine that I could do the rotation / resizing with PdfReader.